# Updating UI from NFC-Tag-Reader event handler is very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, nfc

I have an ACR122U NFC reader where I read MiFare UltraLight NFC tags. I downloaded a framework for my reader. However when the event handler is called, the update of the GUI is very slow.

I have not much experience in threaded programming and event handling. Maybe the solution for my question is very easy.

However it only updates 'label by label' in the UpdateInterface()-method and one all by once. I can see each label disappearing. So the updating of the UI is very slow.

I guess this has something to do with the (hardware-)events called by the reader-classes in background.

The program is generally working only it is very slow.

```
private void StartMonitor()
{
        //Function called when starting the Windows Forms Application
        IMonitorFactory monitorfactory = MonitorFactory.Instance;
        monitor = monitorfactory.Create(SCardScope.System);
        monitor.Start(ReaderNames[0]);
        monitor.StatusChanged += Monitor_StatusChanged;
}

private void Monitor_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangeEventArgs e)
{
        strPassportNo = "";
        strPassportNo = lPassportNumberNo.Text;

        if (e.NewState.ToString().ToLower().Contains("empty".ToLower()) == true)
        {
            //Interface should be deleted all by once now as no NFC tag is on the reader.
            UpdateInterface();
        }
}

private void UpdateInterface()
{
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                lPassportNumberNo.Text = "";
                lPassengerName.Text = "";
                lPax.Text = "";
                lTableNo.Text = "";
                lRoomNo.Text = "";
                pbTables.Hide();
                pbPasspic.Hide();
                this.BackgroundImage = BackgroundWelcome;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            lPassportNumberNo.Text = "";
            lPassengerName.Text = "";
            lPax.Text = "";
            lTableNo.Text = "";
            lRoomNo.Text = "";
            pbTables.Hide();
            pbPasspic.Hide();
            this.BackgroundImage = BackgroundWelcome;
        }
}
```

The expected output should be that the performance of the UI is a lot faster than it is actually. Or at least the labels with data in it should appear and disappear at once.

Comment: Sounds like you want to batch up the NFC updates coming from the monitor.StatusChanged event. I can't see where you are updating the UI though. You need to do those updates on the UI thread using the beginupdate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI-Update was in my case to just clear the labels (see UpdateInterface()). However I found the "error". It was the ".jpg" file als BackgroundImage I loaded on every refresh. Although it was "just" 1280x1024, it was too much for the frontend to update.

When I cleared the Images, the refresh was immediately.

My solution now is:

```
this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Zoom;
this.SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

in the Form1.Designer.cs

and Suspending and Resuming the Layout with the following class (which I found somewhere on the Internet)

```
public static class ControlHelper
{
    #region Redraw Suspend/Resume
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

    public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control target)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target) { ResumeDrawing(target, true); }
    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target, bool redraw)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);

        if (redraw)
        {
            target.Refresh();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Also I changed the ".jpg" files to ".bmp" files. Now the Interface is smooth and fast.

And @Jesting:

> Not sure what is this actually: this.BackgroundImage = BackgroundWelcome; but is it really necessary to assign such static data every time?

No, I could have found a better solution. However as the application is very small and I only have four background images, I found it easier to "hard code" it.

Finally, the tag(-reader) was not really the problem.

And for updating the UI, I use this quite easy function:

```
private void UpdateInterface(PassportDatabaseReader.Passport _passport)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action<PassportDatabaseReader.Passport>(UpdateInterface), new object[] { _passport });
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ControlHelper.SuspendDrawing(this);
            new Thread(() => ChangeBackground(BackgroundPassport)).Start();
            lPassportNumberNo.Text = _passport.PassportNo;
            strPassportNo = _passport.PassportNo;
            lPassengerName.Text = _passport.Name.Replace('$','\n');
            lPax.Text = _passport.Pax;
            lTableNo.Text = _passport.TableNo;
            lRoomNo.Text = _passport.RoomNo;
            pbTables.Hide();
            try
            {
                pbPasspic.Load("..\\..\\Pics\\" + _passport.PassportNo + ".png");
                pbPasspic.Show();
                pbTables.ImageLocation = "..\\..\\Tischordnung_" + _passport.TableNo + ".png";
                pbTables.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            ControlHelper.ResumeDrawing(this);
        }
    }
```

The application is a "wedding passport" reader which shows the name, the guests room number, table number as well as the "passport" picture on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is this actually: `this.BackgroundImage = BackgroundWelcome;` but is it really necessary to assign such static data every time?

Also i dont think that frequency of your update event is too high - information on the screen should be human-readable so it's definitely only one update of all data required after the entire tag is readed. If there are many read events for every single tag - then store all of them into temporary list and update the form at the read end (entire tag).
When i say "tag" i mean the entire mifare card content.